# Super new. Trying to install Wine. Please help

Tags: wine, dependencies

Forgive me if my knowledge is wrong. I'm really just downloading this for a class.

So I've already downloaded Ubuntu (Xenial) and I'm running into some issues in downloading Wine. To my knowledge, I'm running on 32-bit.

Here's the result I get when I try to download it:

```
(xenial)tmcielo@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging:i386 : Depends: wine-staging:i386 (= 4.0~rc7~xenial) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've attempted to install winehq-staging:i386 and wine-staging:i386 but it didn't do anything. 
Help?
Again, forgive my lack of knowledge if I'm missing something. I'm extremely new to this.

Comment: hopefully someone with more knowledge than me will answer but in the mean time try this. FYI `uname -a` will give you some system informatian and tell you if you are running 32 or 64-bit. `sudo apt-get install -f` will try and fix broken dependencies then you can try to install the package again. This page http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/01/install-wine-2-0-ubuntu-16-04-14-04-16-10/ might be useful too.

Comment: "Linux localhost 3.14.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jan 6 23:56:08 PST 2019 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux" that's what I get

Comment: also: nano command not found

Comment: What hardware are you trying to install this on?  From your comment below you are showing ARM7.  ARM is not i386.  The only versions available in the repos are i386 (32bit) and x86_64.

Comment: so, in short, it was a lost cause from the start?

Comment: @taylorc Can you run `uname -a` and confirm what hardware platform you are trying to install it on?

Comment: @taylorc Not necessarily.  It all depends on what you are trying to do.  If you are looking into gaming on a Raspberry Pi, look into things like Retro Pi.  There are instructions out there that claim that you can install Wine on a Raspberry Pi with the aid of a second layer emulator to help out.  Without knowing what your hardware is, it is difficult to say.